# WinJS listView gesture attaching/firing AFTER selection

Tags: javascript, listview, winjs, gestures

I have a WinJS listview that I am attaching a MSGesture to that does not fire on the first tap/click. Once the items have been click/tapped they work on a single tap. This leave me to believe that it is not getting attached right away. It is a MSGestureHold:

```js
    function myEdit() {

        var theelem = document.querySelector(".win-selected #myNotes");

        var gestureObject = new MSGesture();
        gestureObject.target = theelem;
        theelem.gestureObject = gestureObject;

        theelem.addEventListener("pointerdown", pointerDown, false);
        theelem.addEventListener("MSGestureStart", gestureStart, false);            
        theelem.addEventListener("MSGestureHold", gestureHold, false);
        theelem.addEventListener("MSGestureEnd", gestureEnd, false);

        function pointerDown(e) {
            e.target.gestureObject.addPointer(e.pointerId);

            //console.log(e);
        }

        function gestureStart(e) {

        }

        function gestureHold(e){
            console.log(e);

        }

        function gestureEnd(e){
            e.target.gestureObject = null;

        }

    };
```

Calling the function from inside an itemInvokedHandler:

```js
        WinJS.UI.processAll(root).then(function () {

            var listview = document.querySelector('#myNotePad').winControl;
            listview.addEventListener("iteminvoked", itemInvokedHandler,false);

            function itemInvokedHandler(e) {

                e.detail.itemPromise.done(function (invokedItem) {

                    var setelem = document.querySelector(".win-selected #myNotes");
                    setImmediate(setelem.addEventListener("pointerdown", myEdit(), false));

                    //hopeThisWorks();

                    //myEdit();
                });
            };


        });
```

As you can see I've tried to use both a function call and an addEventListener.
Oddly I also have another function that works on styling and it fires right away no problem. Makes me think its how the gesture is handled, or should be anyway.

Now the html that may affect this is:

```js
layout:{type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout},
selectionMode: 'multi', tapBehavior: 'directSelect'
```

I have tried "tapBehavior: invokeOnly" but that kinda breaks everything.

Thanks for take'n a look.

-Rob0

Comment: I believe my problem is understanding how gestures and how eventHandlers are propagated. First off how to properly initiate and clear an eventHandler. Second, how to properly initiate and clear a gesture. Would any one like to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Haha aside from the problem above, the gestureHold is firing twice. Once for the down and the second for the release. Hmmm.

Comment: Found this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn433243.aspx). And will work on it some more